# Error when booting Kubuntu after installing Nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, secure-boot

I was installing Nvidia drivers and it asked me to enter a secure boot password. I entered it and restarted. I then continued with the first choice in the MOK GUI and now my system won't start.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUWmQ.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Enter a TTY on boot and reinstall the Nvidia drivers.

Found the answer here: https://gist.github.com/bitsurgeon/b0f4440984c9e60dcd8fe8bbc346c029